# Visual Basic 2010 Serial port reading?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I have application which is a microcontroller send a string of 20 bytes (numbers as text separated by comma) over UART in rate of 140 string/second and save the result into text file, i try using visual basic 2010 with serial port control component, the serialport component properties are ReadBufferSize = 20 & ReceivedBytesThreshold = 20, it is work fine but some times it receive more than 20 byte in single line which cause an error like this :

```
382 ,387 ,387 ,172 ,
382 ,385 ,388 ,172 ,
382 ,390 ,389 ,172 ,
382 ,384 ,389 ,172 ,382 ,387 ,392 ,172 ,
383 ,387 ,389 ,172 ,
```

Thanks for your help

the code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter 
    Dim sread0 As String

    Dim swo = 0




    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

        If (SerialPort1.IsOpen) Then
            SerialPort1.Close()

        End If

        If swo = 1 Then
            sw.Close()

        End If

    End Sub




    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        c1.Items.AddRange(myPort)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error GoTo j1
        swo = 1
        sw = New IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\" & pname.Text & ".txt")
        SerialPort1.PortName = c1.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = "115200" 'c2.Text




        SerialPort1.Open()


    End Sub


    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived



        sread0 = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()

        sw.WriteLine("{0}", sread0)




    End Sub


        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'On Error GoTo u
        If (SerialPort1.IsOpen) Then
            SerialPort1.Close()

        End If

        If swo = 1 Then
            sw.Close()

        End If

        Application.Exit()
        Exit Sub

u:
        MsgBox(Err.Description)

    End Sub




End Class
```

Comment: "it is work fine but some times it receive more than 20 byte in single line which cause an error" gives a hint for educated guessing, but it'S not a precise error description. Please always add a precise error description to your questions!

Comment: Hi, i put example of occurred error, thanks for your attention

Comment: Setting the ReadBufferSize to 20 will not work, the driver will ignore that.  So you'll get more once in a while, happens when the event handler is a bit slow at starting to run.  You need to fix this by using Read() and count off the bytes.

Comment: Dear Hans, would you please suggest any example ?